# Выборка по нескольким значениям в многоуровневом массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Прошу помочь в следующей для меня головоломке.

Имеется многоуровневый массив. Ниже представлен его отрывок в виде продукта с названием "Фланец", у которого имеется множество (в данном примере 3) предложений (OFFERS). Эти торговые предложения различаются по следующим свойствам: Ду, Ру и марка стали.

В одном списке необходимо вывести название и цены фланцев с маркой стали 20 и значением Ру 16 всех значений Ду. В другом - с маркой стали 40 и значением Ру 16 всех значений Ду.

То есть выборка должна происходить сразу по нескольким свойствам (Сталь и Ду). В MySQL это можно было бы осуществить с помощью "WHERE", а здесь ничего не приходит в голову.

Моих знаний хватило на следующий код, который выводит значения только по одному свойству:

```
<?php
    $offers = Array();

foreach($offers as $value) {
    foreach($value['PROPERTIES'] as $key => $property) {
        if($key == 'STEEL') {
            if($property['VALUE'] == 20) {
                echo $value['NAME'];
                echo '<br />';
                echo $value['PRICE'];
                echo '<br />';  
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

Array
(
    [ID] => 678
    [NAME] => Фланец
    [OFFERS] => Array
        (
         [0] => Array
             (
                [ID] => 23
                [NAME] => Фланец Ду 15 Ру 16 Сталь 20
                [PRICE] => 340
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                       [DU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 22
                               [NAME] => Ду
                               [VALUE] => 15
                            )
                       [RU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 32
                               [NAME] => Ру
                               [VALUE] => 16
                            )
                       [STEEL] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 36
                               [NAME] => Сталь
                               [VALUE] => 20
                            )
                     )
              )
         [1] => Array
             (
                [ID] => 24
                [NAME] => Фланец Ду 25 Ру 16 Сталь 20
                [PRICE] => 420
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                       [DU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 23
                               [NAME] => Ду
                               [VALUE] => 25
                            )
                       [RU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 33
                               [NAME] => Ру
                               [VALUE] => 16
                            )
                       [STEEL] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 37
                               [NAME] => Сталь
                               [VALUE] => 20
                            )
                     )
              )
         [2] => Array
             (
                [ID] => 25
                [NAME] => Фланец Ду 15 Ру 16 Сталь 40
                [PRICE] => 420
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                       [DU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 24
                               [NAME] => Ду
                               [VALUE] => 15
                            )
                       [RU] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 34
                               [NAME] => Ру
                               [VALUE] => 16
                            )
                       [STEEL] => Array
                           (
                               [ID] => 38
                               [NAME] => Сталь
                               [VALUE] => 40
                            )
                     )
              )
      )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$arr** - ваш исходный массив

```
function sifting($v){
    return $v['PROPERTIES']['STEEL']['VALUE'] == 20 && $v['PROPERTIES']['RU']['VALUE'] == 16;
}
$flan = array_filter($arr['OFFERS'], 'sifting');
foreach($flan as $val){
    echo $val['NAME'] , ', Цена: ' , $val['PRICE'] , '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: К сожалению, в функции sifting нельзя передавать параметры, а хотелось бы обернуть весь код в одну функцию, в которой засчёт подмены параметров (например сталь 20, ру 16) выводились соответствующие значения.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: @andre3000, делайте так:

    $flan = array_filter($arr['OFFERS'], function($a) use($b, $c){
       return $a['PROPERTIES']['STEEL']['VALUE'] == $b && $a['PROPERTIES']['RU']['VALUE'] == $c;

    });

$b и $c - это ваши параметры

Comment: И ещё раз большое спасибо!